# Hudson Java version returned is different

Tags: java, windows, hudson, aix, master-slave

Hi guys I am trying to connect a AIX server Slave machine to a Windows Master Slave machine. Below are my configuration page.

[image: Hudson Slave configuration page]

The JRE version found on the AIX server are this(java path on top, and I did not include the /bin because Hudson automatically adds them when trying to run; see log below):

```
gbnruad0016:/usr/java5/jre/bin/

java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap32devifx-20110627 (SR12     FP5 ))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223ifx-20110624 (JIT  enabled)
J9VM - 20110623_85457_bHdSMr
JIT  - 20100623_16197ifx10_r8
GC   - FP22011_06)
JCL  - 20110627
```

However when I want to run the slave agent, I got these error,

```
[10/23/13 04:07:58] [SSH] Checking java version of java
[10/23/13 04:07:58] [SSH] java -version returned 1.4.2.
[10/23/13 04:07:58] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/bin/java
Couldn't figure out the Java version of /usr/bin/java

[10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/java/default/bin/java
[10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/java/latest/bin/java
[10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/local/bin/java
[10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/local/java/bin/java
[10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Checking java version of /gcdm/sys/cdms011/hudson/jdk/bin/java
[10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/java5/bin/java
hudson.util.IOException2: Could not find any known supported java version in   [java, /usr/bin/java, /usr/java/default/bin/java, /usr/java/latest/bin/java, /usr/local/bin    /java, /usr/local/java/bin/java, /gcdm/sys/cdms011/hudson/jdk/bin/java, /usr/java5/bin/    java], and we also failed to install JDK as a fallback
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.resolveJava(SSHLauncher.java:230)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.launch(SSHLauncher.java:184)
at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:184)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sorry, this connection is closed.
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.sendMessage(TransportManager.java:637)
at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.openSessionChannel (ChannelManager.java:582)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Session.<init>(Session.java:40)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.openSession(Connection.java:1047)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.exec(Connection.java:1434)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.attemptToInstallJDK(SSHLauncher.java:253)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.resolveJava(SSHLauncher.java:228)
... 7 more
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA message  for non-existent channel 103
at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.msgChannelExtendedData (ChannelManager.java:832)
at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.handleMessage(ChannelManager.java:1639)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:775)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:470)
... 1 more
     [10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I don't know where did the version 1.4.2 came from? I checked on my local machine, its 1.6.0, and on AIX server, its 1.5.0.

Maybe that is the root cause to this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your error log above

> [10/23/13 04:07:59] [SSH] Checking java version of **/usr/java5/bin/java**
>   hudson.util.IOException2: Could not find any known supported java version in   [java, /usr/bin/java, /usr/java/default/bin/java, /usr/java/latest/bin/java, /usr/local/bin    /java, /usr/local/java/bin/java, /gcdm/sys/cdms011/hudson/jdk/bin/java, **/usr/java5/bin/    java**], and we also failed to install JDK as a fallback

My first suspicion is that you either don't have java5 installed or that you don't have permission on your /usr/java5 installation.

UPDATE: Read the question again and noticed that your java path is `/usr/java5/jre` and not `/usr/java5`. May be that helps.